# TCPIP server using Matlab connecting but not receiving

Tags: c++, matlab, tcp, server

I'm trying to generate a TCPIP server in matlab that is supposed to communicate with a TCPIP client coded in C++. Until now I got this working :

- C++ Server and Matlab Client (UDP and TCPIP)
- C++ client and Matlab Server (UDP only)

My C++ client should be OK (That's why I'm not giving the code which is way too long for this question), I made it work with the simple commands in Python.

In my Matlab server, the connection is made but the fread function does not seem to read anything... However, the data are well sent in the C++ client part. Here's my Matlab code:

```
u=tcpip('localhost', 50000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(u);
%[data,count]=fread(u,6*8,'uint8'); %this doesn't work either
data=fread(u);
```

My C++ client is also on 'localhost' and the specified port is 50000 for the server. I suppose that's why the connection is made. I don't understand what's happening here. I thank you in advance for all your answers.

EDIT : I tested with echotcpip('on',50000) and it's working (but I don't need echo function by the way).

EDIT2 : fwrite(u,somedata) works perfectly... I can't get why fread is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late : You need to listen to any ip addresses of the server not only on "localhost" (that is only 127.0.0.1). You should write *u=tcpip('0.0.0.0', 50000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');*

Comment: Not too late at all. However, it does not seem to work either. But thank you for your help !